# Entity Framework - SQL Query - Limit and Order By - SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, frameworks, entity

So i have this code:

```
List<User> topuser = db.Database.SqlQuery<User>("SELECT * FROM Users LIMIT 5 ORDER BY DimensaoRede DESC").ToList();
```

When i try and run it in the context of my application it says:

Incorrect syntax near '5'

Can someone help me? Is the query wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: yes. I'm gonna edit the question so everyone knows

Comment: Try `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Users ORDER BY DimensaoRede DESC`.

Comment: SQL server down not support limit - that is MySql syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server doesnt support `limit`.

To use sql server your query would need to look like this:

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM Users ORDER BY DimensaoRede DESC
```

Limit works on MySQL and Postgres, but will fail on SQL Server.

[TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) is how to "limit" your results in SQL Server

Answer (score 4):

try this query

```
SELECT top 5 * FROM Users ORDER BY DimensaoRede DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Limit is MySQL construct. In SQL Server you need to use TOP:

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Users ORDER BY DimensaoRede DESC
```